# nginx and auth_basic

Tags: nginx, basic-authentication, .htpasswd

I am trying to get basic authentication working with nginx in Ubuntu Jaunty.  In nginx.conf, I added these two lines under the server context:

```
server {
   ...
   auth_basic "Restricted Access";
   auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
   ...
}
```

Then I apt-get'ed apache2-utils to get htpasswd, which I used to create the htpasswd file:

```
htpasswd -d -c /etc/nginx/.htpasswd joe
```

When I try to access the site, the authentication dialog comes up as expected, but when I put in the username and password, it just refreshed the dialog box.  It doesn't seem to like the password I am providing it.  I tried running htpasswd both with and without the -d option, but still no luck.  It refused to authenticate.  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try relative path for "auth_basic_user_file"?

Comment: @KP can you share what fixed this for you?

Answer (score 30):

Things I would check:

- Permissions on `/etc/nginx/.htpasswd` - Can the file be read by the account running nginx? You could try, temporarily, using `chmod 644` to make sure everyone can read it. If that works, then you can sort out an appropriate combination of `chown` and `chmod` settings so that nginx and you/root can read it but other users cannot (for security).
- Ensure that `htpasswd` is generating the hash in the right form; it's usually about 13 alphanumeric characters (for example `username:wu.miGq/e3nro`). The command CAN generate MD5 hashes too which would look more like `username:$apr1$hzB2K...$b87zlCYMKufOxn9ol5QV4/` these don't work with nginx.
- Look into increasing the debug output of nginx and check the error logs for clues.

Comment: according to the docs at http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_basic_module.html "the Apache variant of the MD5-based password algorithm (apr1)" is now supported

Comment: Even docs points that the "Apache variant is now supported", I only solved this problem using a PLAIN algorithm. Unfortunately, with debug log in nginx, the message was still "open() ".htpasswd" failed (13: Permission denied)", which probably is the internal root cause of the problem (looking under nginx's developer perspective), but is useless when you're trying to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 12):

Old thread, but no answer, and well referenced on Google.

If you get this error and have tried the other suggestions, check the permissions of the **parent folder** of your .htpasswd file: the nginx user (www-data by default) should have read **and execute** permissions (this fixed it for me).

Answer (score 7):

Another gotcha I ran into on bash. Instead of entering my password via prompt I used the `-b` option of `htpasswd` to enter the password in-line.

```
$ htpasswd -nb admin test123$secure
```

I couldn't understand why my I kept on running into password mismatch errors, trying different encryption algorithms. I verified with curl that it worked:

```
$ curl -u admin:test123$secure https://example.com
```

Finally, the problem reveiled itself through `echo`

```
$ echo test123$secure
test123
```

I made the mistake of using a **dolar sign ($)** in bash which was interpreted as an empty variable, thus omitting everything else. This can be avoided by dropping the `-b` option and just using the prompt to enter the password.

Answer (score 0):

nginx recognize 401 response as logout, make sure your site is not returning 401 and redirecting again, it will fall into infinite login loop as logged in -> 401 -> logged out -> redirect to same page -> repeat