# Elasticsearch basic auth with nginx

Tags: nginx, elasticsearch

I have the following set-up:

> /etc/nginx/sites-available/elasticsearch

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
    auth_basic "Elasticsearch Authentication";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/elasticsearch/es.pwd;

    location / {
        rewrite ^/(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_ignore_client_abort on;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:9200;
        proxy_redirect http://localhost:9200 http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/;
        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header  Host $http_host;
    }
}
```

whenever I do

> curl -i -u user:pass http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/

I get *401 Authorization Required*

If I remove the auth_basic from nginx conf, everything works smoothly.
It's clear to me that the auth bit is problemmatic. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: yep it was like that when i started. i followed this guide: http://www.minvolai.com/blog/2014/08/Setting-up-a-Secure-Single-Node-Elasticsearch-server-behind-Nginx/Setting-up-a-Secure-Single-Node-Elasticsearch-server-behind-Nginx/

Comment: follow this thread instructions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010677/nginx-and-auth-basic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the way the password was encrypted. when I generated the password, I used bcrypt. more info [here](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nginx/+question/263001).

I've deleted the old pass and creaded a new one with md5(through htpasswd) and works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

It seems rather probable that the phenomena has to do with your nginx configuration rather than with Elasticsearch. For instance, the password file `.htpasswd` might not have the appropriate rights or is placed in the wrong folder which is not accessible for nginx.