# Nginx authentication issues when building mlflow through docker-compose

Tags: docker, debugging, nginx, google-cloud-platform, mlflow

I'm trying to dockerize [mlflow](https://mlflow.org/) with PostgreSQL and nginx configurations for Google Cloud Run (GCR) on the Google Cloud Platform (GCP).

Before deploying anything to GCP however, I wanted to get a local deployment working. I found [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/deploy-mlflow-with-docker-compose-8059f16b6039) guide that details the process of setting up the environment. Having followed the guide (excluding the SQL part), I can see the  mlflow UI on `localhost:80` as nginx redirects traffic on port 80 to 5000. To add authentication, I found [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-password-authentication-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04) that I can do it using `sudo htpasswd -c .htpasswd <username>` in the `etc/nginx/` directory and then adding

```
location \ {
   auth_basic "Private Property";
   auth_basic_user_file .htpasswd;
}
```

to the `nginx.conf` (or `mlflow.conf` in this case) to make it appear online. Trouble is, when I go to `localhost:80` *now* and enter in my username/password, I continue to see

```
[error] 6#6: *1 open() "/etc/nginx/.htpasswd" failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

in the `docker-compose up` logs as they are printed to the terminal, and as such *I'm not able to see the mlflow UI* on `localhost:80` (either a blank screen or nginx 403 error).

Now, I've looked at several other posts (such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010677/nginx-and-auth-basic) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16510374/403-forbidden-nginx-using-correct-credentials)) and it seems to me that nginx doesn't have the right permissions to read the `.htpasswd` in the `etc/nginx/` directory file or that the path of the file isn't correct, i.e. the path has to be in reference to the `nginx.conf` file.

Even though I made these corrections to the above towards-data-science files, the problem still persists.  I've been stuck for a while on this. Any particular reasons why this may be happening?

Edit:
Here is my directory structure in case it may help:

```
mlflow-docker/:
  mlflow/:
    Dockerfile
  nginx/:
    Dockerfile
    mlflow.conf
    nginx.conf
  docker-compose.yml
```

Comment: can you share the nginx dockerfile

Comment: If you scroll down to "Containerization" in the towards-data-science article, you'll be able to see both the nginx and mlflow dockerfiles. [This](https://towardsdatascience.com/deploy-mlflow-with-docker-compose-8059f16b6039) is the article.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the .htpasswd file inside your container's file system.

Generate the password file in your project's nginx folder.

```
sudo htpasswd -c .htpasswd sammy
```

Copy the password file to the nginx container's directory. Add following line in nginx dockerfile.

```
COPY .htpasswd /etc/nginx
```